# Why is this important to the proof of any sequence of digits being equivalent to a number? Vladimir A. Zorich, Mathematical Analysis I, 2nd ed.

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

This question refers to a particular proof in Zorich's Mathematical Analysis I (2nd edition) and, thus, is only relevant for those who have the book because it would be challenging to explain the context of the question concisely.

In the proof that any sequence of digits is equivalent to a number (**page 64**), we prove that we cannot have successive $q-1$s infinitely, and I agree. Then one formally sums up that fact in the inequality (2.10). That's also clear. But it seems we don't need that fact to show that there are strict inequalities in (2.11) (even arbitrarily far, at least in either left-hand or right-hand sequence). Though, there is a reference to (2.10) when one underlines that: "This follows from (2.10)."

I understand why we need strict inequalities arbitrarily far, at least in one part of the sequence. Otherwise, there would be a gap between the supremum of the left-hand sequence and the infimum of the right-hand one. However, I don't think we need to use (2.10) to show that.

But if we don't rely on (2.10) to prove the equivalence between sequences of digits and real numbers, yet we show (2.10) separately, i.e., the fact that we cannot have successive $q-1$s infinitely, then it might be that we implicitly assume there are other *forbidden* subsequences.

[image]

Comment: What does "any sequence of digits is equivalent to a number" mean?

Comment: @lulu They are doing base $q$ representation.

Comment: @Seeker I don't have the book and didn't read carefully the quoted portion, but the assumption of not having a tail of $q-1$ in the sequence helps to have uniqueness, one sequence of *digits* corresponding to a unique real number. The thing is that if a sequence $a_p...$ ends in a tail of $q-1$ that starts at $a_k$, then it corresponds to the same number as the sequence $a_p...(a_{k-1}+1)000...$. If allowing tails of $q-1$ spoils something in their argument, it is fixable. Perhaps that $<$ in 2.11 becoming $\leq$.

Comment: @NDB, we can prove that various sequences correspond to different numbers from the construction algorithm itself, can't we? In each step, we use Archimedes' principle, which assumes the uniqueness of the digit. I think it's enough for that purpose. So I think the fact we cannot have the infinite sequence of $q-1$s is somehow essential to the proof, but I don't see how.

Comment: You might have seen how in base $10$ the sequences $1.000...$ and $0.999...$ correspond to the same real number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the answer to the question, i.e., why (2.10) is crucial.

At first, I thought one needs it to guarantee that $\mathtt{sup}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}r_n = \mathtt{inf}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(r_n+q^{-(n-p)})$, but one can see that we do not need (2.10) to prove that. Then we can uniquely define $x$ for any sequence, including ones with unending successive $q-1$s. However, we know we cannot obtain a sequence ending with infinite successive $q-1$s from any $x$ following the algorithm because of (2.10). It turns out that for such sequences, $\exists k\in\mathbb{N}:\mathtt{inf}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(r_n+q^{-(n-p)}) = r_k+q^{-(k-p)}$, and, thus, $x = r_k+q^{-(k-p)}$. But it entails that x violates (2.8).
[image]

That means applying the algorithm to $x$ would result in another sequence of digits. Thus, without assuming (2.10), the proof that any sequence of digits corresponds to a positive number if applying the algorithm is incomplete. However, one can show that (2.10) is a necessary and sufficient condition for (2.8). In other words, (2.10) guarantees that $\mathtt{inf}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(r_n+q^{-(n-p)})$ and, thus, $x$ is strictly less than $r_n+q^{-(n-p)}$ for all $n$. Then $x$ satisfies (2.8), which concludes the proof that there is a one-to-one correspondence between positive numbers and sequences of digits without unending successive $q-1$s.

Now this seems obvious, yet at first, the necessity of (2.10) was indeed obscure.